# Retrieving output values from stored procedure - GetColumn

Tags: oracle10g, java-stored-procedures

I need to invoke a stored procedure and it has no OUT parameters instead it writes to the buffer manager  by calling putcolumn.How can I retrieve the data set using put column from a JAVA application.
My stored procedure is an oracle on.Can someone provide your inputs to sort my issue?

Comment: What does "it writes to the buffer manager by calling putcolumn" mean?  Do you mean that it writes to the buffer maintained by the `dbms_output` package by calling `dbms_output.put_line`?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with "calling putcolumn" from an Oracle stored procedure. Can you provide an example of the call you are making? Is "putcolumn" a stored procedure or function?